# Why doesn't Flow.onCompletion get called for ConflatedBroadcacstChannel.asFlow()?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

In [the new Android code lab for Coroutines+Flow/LiveData](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-kotlin-coroutines/#0) you update a LiveData api to use Flow, but I noticed some unintended behavior around `onCompletion` not getting called as expected. The LiveData code we are replacing:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
  try {
    _spinner.value = true
  ...query some data...
  } catch (error: Throwable) {
    _snackbar.value = error.message
  } finally {
    _spinner.value = false
  }
}
```

The Flow code we get at the end of the code lab:

```
val growZoneChannel = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<Int>()
...
growZoneChannel.asFlow()
       .mapLatest { growZone ->
           _spinner.value = true
           ...query some data...
       }
       .onCompletion {  _spinner.value = false }
       .catch { throwable ->  _snackbar.value = throwable.message  }
       .launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

When you run the Flow the spinner never disappears because onCompletion is never called even when the `mapLatest` transform completes. The code lab states, "`onCompletion` will be called every time the flow above it completes. It's the same thing as a finally block – it's a good place to put any code you need to execute during cleanup. Here we're resetting the spinner."

But this is clearly not true. So what would be the proper way to execute a code black after each transform, and does this mean the code lab is incorrect or is there something I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: `onCompletion` is called when `close` is called on the `growZoneChannel`. Where do you close your channel?

Comment: Because `growZoneChannel` is getting values from UI events I never closed it because the user could select a new grow zone and then we wouldn't be able to offer a new value to a closed channel right?

Comment: No, you can't send more values to a closed channel. Maybe you could close the old channel and create a new one when that happens? You gotta close it if you want the `onCompletion`-block to run.

Comment: You have misunderstood the meaning of "flow completing". You seem to think it means that the transformation of a single item completes, but it actually means that the whole flow completes. If you want to add actions to perform on each item, just add those to the `mapLatest` block, in a `try-finally` block if that's what you need.

Comment: How were you sending items to your `growZoneChannel`?